# How to know if a certain x-y coordinate is within a rectangle?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, awt

I have a `JPanel` on a `JFrame` and a rectangle has been drawn on it. I've to know whether a specified coordinate is within that rectangle. How do I do this? I'm talking about library functions. Thanks.

Comment: `Rectangle#contains`...

Comment: *"I'm talking about library functions."*  If you need a library function for something so basic, I'd wonder if you were cut out for programming..

Comment: Actually, there are about hundreds of rectangles. If I make a method myself(I'm a beginner), I'll have to write a lot of code. So I was wondering if there is a method already in Java

Comment: *"there are about hundreds of rectangles. If I make a method myself(I'm a beginner), I'll have to write a lot of code.."*  No, what would be better is a single method (e.g. `isPointInRectangle(..)`) called each time with one `Rectangle` and one `Point`.

Answer (score 2):

Given the complete vagueness of the question, I would suggest using [`java.awt.Rectangle#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#contains(int,%20int)) which has several flavours to make life easier for you....

You might consider also having a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more some ideas...